# When is a commutative ring the limit of its factor rings?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Consider the limit of rings $L = lim_{I \in Spec(R)}(R/I)$. Then there is a canonical map $R \to L$. The question is when this map is an isomorphism.

For example, this is true if $R$ is an integral domain. If $R = k[x]/(x^2)$, then this is false. Is it true for every reduced ring? If it is not, then which rings have this property?

Comment: The kernel of this map is the nilradical of $R$ (that is the intersection of all prime ideals), so $R\to L$ is injective iff $R$ is reduced. I'm not sure if the map is always surjective but I suspect so

Comment: Here are some counterexamples to surjectivity: (1) Let $R = k[x,y]/y(y-x^2)$. The minimal primes are $(y)$ and $(y-x^2)$. There is a unique element of the limit which is $0$ modulo $y$ and $x$ modulo $y-x^2$, but it doesn't lift to $R$ because $0 \not \equiv x \bmod \langle y, y-x^2 \rangle$. (2) Let $R = k[x,y]/xy(x-y)$. The minimal primes are $(x)$, $(y)$ and $(x-y)$. There is an element of the limit which is $0$, $0$ and $x$ modulo these primes, but it does not lift to $R$, because $0 \not \equiv x \bmod (x-y) + ((x) \cap (y))$.

Comment: The first two examples seem like they have something to do with the rings not being seminormal. Here is a non-noetherian example of a different flavor. Let $S$ be the infinite polynomial ring $k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$ and set $R = S/\langle x_i x_j \rangle_{i \neq j}$. The minimal primes are $I_j := \langle x_k \rangle_{k \neq j}$. There is an element of the inverse limit which is $x_j$ modulo $I_j$. Morally, it wants to lift to $\sum x_i$, but that isn't in $R$.

Comment: Similar to David's first comment, see also Julian Rosen's answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597245/chinese-remainder-theorem-as-sheaf-condition